# Pump bytes from asyncio StreamReader into a file descriptor

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a Python function (implemented in C++) that reads from a file descriptor (wrapped in `FILE*` on the C++ side) and I need to feed the function from an `asyncio.StreamReader`. Specifically, the reader is the content of a HTTP response: [aiohttp.ClientResponse.content](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.content).

I thought I might [open a pipe](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html?highlight=fdopen#os.pipe), pass the read-end to the C++ function and [connect the write-end](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.connect_write_pipe) to `asyncio`'s event loop. However, how can I move the data from the stream reader to the pipe, with proper flow control and as little copying as possible?

The skeleton of the code with the missing parts is as following:

```
# obtain the StreamReader from aiohttp
content = aiohttp_client_response.content
# create a pipe
(pipe_read_fd, pipe_write_fd) = os.pipe()

# now I need a suitable protocol to manage the pipe transport
protocol = ?
(pipe_transport, __) = loop.connect_write_pipe(lambda: protocol, pipe_write_fd)

# the protocol should start reading from `content` and writing into the pipe
return pipe_read_fd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [subprocess_attach_write_pipe](https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/master/examples/subprocess_attach_write_pipe.py) asyncio example:

```
rfd, wfd = os.pipe()
pipe = open(wfd, 'wb', 0)
transport, _ = await loop.connect_write_pipe(asyncio.Protocol, pipe)
transport.write(b'data')
```

---

EDIT - For write flow control, see the following methods:

- [WriteTransport.set_write_buffer_limits](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html?highlight=sendto#asyncio.WriteTransport.set_write_buffer_limits)
- [BaseProtocol.pause_writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html?highlight=sendto#asyncio.BaseProtocol.pause_writing)
- [BaseProtocol.resume_writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html?highlight=sendto#asyncio.BaseProtocol.resume_writing)

Here's a possible `FlowControl` implementation, inspired by [StreamWriter.drain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html?highlight=stream#asyncio.StreamWriter.drain):

```
class FlowControl(asyncio.streams.FlowControlMixin):
    async def drain(self):
        await self._drain_helper()
```

Usage:

```
transport, protocol = await loop.connect_write_pipe(FlowControl, pipe)
transport.write(b'data')
await protocol.drain()
```

Comment: This shows how to open the pipe for writing with asyncio, but does not show how to correctly copy to the pipe from an `asyncio.StreamReader`. In particular, simply reading chunks of bytes from the reader and feeding them to `transport.write` may overflow buffers if the party reading from the pipe is too slow to keep up with the `StreamReader`.

Comment: @JanŠpaček See my edit about write flow control, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this issue by using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and blocking calls to `os.write`:

```
(read_fd, write_fd) = os.pipe()
task_1 = loop.create_task(pump_bytes_into_fd(write_fd))
task_2 = loop.run_in_executor(executor_1, parse_bytes_from_fd(read_fd))

async def pump_bytes_into_fd(write_fd):
    while True:
        chunk = await stream.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
        if chunk is None: break
        # process the chunk
        await loop.run_in_executor(executor_2, os.write, write_fd, chunk)
```

It is crucial that two different executors are used for blocking reads and writes to avoid deadlocks.